# Not ablet to bind address through webrick on rails on Ubuntu AMI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick, amazon-ami

I have got rails setup on linux (ubuntu)ami. I am trying to bind the ip used to access linux ami but am not able to bind it." Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL) "
Full rails setup seems to be fine. 
Am missing something here. The exact need is to access the rails app through different pc.

Plz point me to some ref.

Comment: `bind(2)` reports, "A nonexistent interface was requested or the requested source address was not local.". Are you sure you used the correct address? Can you use `INADDR_ANY`?

Answer (score 0):

I may not be fully understanding your request but starting your rails server on a particular port:

```
rails s -p 3000 #rails 3
script/server -p 3000 #rails 2
```

Then you should be able to access this on a different pc by going to:

```
http://yourmachinename:3000
```

If new Pc is on the same network. Otherwise have a look at your firewall settings and open up port 3000 and point it to the local IP of your machine (you can get this from ifconfig). Then get the external IP of your local network and go to:

```
http://your.external.ip:3000/
```